# Visual Studio 2019 - Nuget package restore failed

Tags: visual-studio

Recently I install the Visual Studio 2019 on my PC to work on a project that I'm developing at my internship but when I open the project on my PC, an error occurs at the nuget package manager console, the error is:

```
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
```

[image: NuGet package restore failure message]

When I go to Error List, the errors shown are these:

[image: Errors]

Then I go to the dependencies NuGet and I see this:

[image: NuGet Dependencies]

Finally when I try to add a new Package the package manager console send this Message:

[image: Install-Package messages]

Remembering that the Visual Studio version that I use on my internship is also 2019.

I've tried to search the solution several times but nothing that was shown resulted. So I hope you can help me.

Comment: I had this ***same EXACT problem*** with 2019.  Very strange but after the nuget errors, I opened the project with 2017 and built it.. (no error)... now I can't repro the problem in 2019.  Its like the 2017 build 'fixed something' but I don't know how or what.

Comment: Have you tried to remove and add the NuGet packages (within VS2019) instead of VS2017?

Comment: It seems it has to do with packages.config. I used [Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) and then it worked, even with older package versions.